Kotlin + RestAssured api call returns corrupted body time by time
I have faced with a strange behaviour in my api tests - sometimes I am receiving responses with a corrupted body. Example of correct response:
{
   "lotto":{
      "lottoId":5,
      "winning-numbers":[2,45,34,23,7,5,3],
      "winners":[
         {
            "winnerId":23,
            "numbers":[2,45,34,23,3,5]
         },
         {
            "winnerId":54,
            "numbers":[52,3,12,11,18,22]
         }
      ]
   }
}

And I am receiving something like this:
{
   "lotto":{
      "lottoId":5,

It may happen with any api call. There is nothing special with the way how I am sending requests.
